# T4 Template Processing Error: "Failed to resolve type for directive processor <directive processor name>."

Tags: visual-studio-2012, t4

So I've been having this really nasty error that I've been trying to get rid of for the past couple of days...

I have a T4 template that I run in the debugging solution of a Domain Specific Language (DSL) that I'm building (let's assume it's called MyDsl :P). I have this as the template header:

```
<#@ template inherits="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.ModelingTextTransformation" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ MyDsl processor="MyDslDirectiveProcessor" requires="fileName='Sample.mydsl'" #>
```

The issue is caused by the custom directive, which prevents template generation because it "Failed to resolve type for directive processor MyDslDirectiveProcessor." When I remove the custom directive to try to see if the error depends on something else, I get an error in the first (template) directive, that ModelingTextTransformation does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.

This also happens with the automatically-added templates in this debugging solution, since they contain these same code lines.

Help is appreciated :)

P.S: I use Visual Studio 2012. Also, possible similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311627/t4-template-error).

Comment: Is your "MyDSL" properly deployed? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138364.aspx

Comment: Yes, it was. See answer for what went wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I accidentally renamed my project name in DSL Explorer...I was probably naming something else and my computer went stupid on me without me realizing it.